# How to avoid the configuring ms office dialog box

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I always see the configuring ms office with a an endless progress bar, 2 or more weeks after I installed ms office(2000, 2003, 2010 beta). I'm not exactly sure what it is called but it is trying to configure ms office.Or maybe repairing the installation. And it sucks because when I need to access ms word NOW, I can only see that box with the progress bar. And when I press cancel, it won't open ms word, or maybe the whole suite(ms word, powerpoint, excel)
What might be a possible solution to this?anyone here who has encountered it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of word installed and switch between them it will always do the configure thing when launching that version for the first time as it registers that version's dlls etc (it basically does a Detect/Repair)

i.e.

1. launch 2000 for first time - configure dialog
2. launch 2000 for second time - no configure dialog
3. launch 2003 for first time - configure dialog
4. launch 2003 for second time - no configure dialog
5. launch 2000 for first time - configure dialog
6. launch 2000 for second time - no configure dialog

etc etc

Comment: Running multiple versions is not recommended, especially running 2000 and 2003 on the same computer.  They don't play well together on the same computer.  If you really need to have all three, I would recommend installing the other 2 versions in VM's and accessing them that way.

Comment: I used to have to run this set up for support purposes - the bulk of our users ran 2000 but we in IT Dept had 2003 then later 2007. 99% of my time I used 2003/7 but for those times I needed to launch 2000 for a support call it was quicker to wait for the dialog to finish than to launch a VM.